# Wordpress and Paths

Tags: wordpress, codex

I am setting up a Wordpress site for educational purposes.. the content that I want to show in the wordpress blogs (videos) does however not reside in the wp-content directory but in the Root directory of the server of which Wordpress is a Subdirectory on the same server

Server root

-root

--worpress <-- wordpress

--content <-- my video content going many levels deep

in my Posts i do not want to use the ip address but rather a function that is written into my WordPress functions where i can once define the server ip address of this server before hand and call it in every post and page !

So.. how/where do i define the ip address and how do i call it in my wordpress post to make mediaelement.js media player find the video file?

Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way may be to just use symlinks. So say the media player expects the files to be at `wp-content/videos` directory, but you want the videos to be placed in `/var/www/videos` directory. You can create a symlink to this videos directory inside the wp-content directory.

```
ln -s /path/to/wp-content/videos /var/www/videos
```

Depending on configuration, You may also need to add `FollowSymLinks` to your `.htaccess` file to allow symlinks.

### Edit: Post clarification

You can move the `wp-content` directory to outside the Wordpress directory, by modifying your `wp-config.php`.

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/path/to/content');
```

To move just the plugins directory,

```
define('WP_PLUGIN_DIR', '/path/to/plugins');
```

To move the directory where uploads are stored,

```
define('UPLOADS', '/path/to/uploads');
```

Comment: Darshan. Thank you for your answer. However I am doing this as a solution that will run portable per school I am using [link](http://www.usbwebserver.net/en/) to host the mini WordPress portal and thus using .htaccess  and creating virtual directories not possible.. I am forced to find a solution where I can redirect the link to the video "back to" or "one up" from the WordPress root.